# Schema details empty for a postgres database shown in Intellij Database viewer

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to using the Intellij Database tools.  I set up a connection successfully and the DB is properly introspected. But then the schemas are not available:

[image]

What am I missing/ what should be done differently?

Comment: you need to click on '0 of 3' link next to 'clipnew' and select target schemas.

Comment: @YuriWin  Thx!  Pls make an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to click on '0 of 3' link next to 'clipnew' and select target schemas.